# how to add a dataframe with another dataframe and add common columns values based on a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My first data frame:

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'CONTRACT':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
            'buy_qty':[20, 40, 50, 60],
            'buy_val':[100,120,140,160],
            'factor':[15,20,25,30],
            })
    
        CONTRACT    buy_qty buy_val factor
    0   Tom          20      100    96
    1   nick         40      110    93
    2   krish        50      140    91
    3   jack         60      160    83
```

Second data frame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'CONTRACT': ['Tom', 'nick', 'amit', 'joy'],
            'buy_qty': [5, 6, 15, 30],
            'buy_val': [15, 20, 35, 16],
            'factor': [67, 89, 76, 69]}

df2:
        CONTRACT    buy_qty buy_val factor
    0   Tom           5     15       67
    1   nick          6     20       89
    2   amit          15    35       76
    3   joy           30    16       69
```

I want dataframe Like this (all CONTRACT values of df2 and *uncommon* CONTRACT values of df1, by adding common CONTRACTS's buy_qty and buy_val and factor will be from df2(latest data frame)  ...)-

```
        CONTRACT    buy_qty  buy_val  factor
    0   Tom         25*        115*      67
    1   nick        46*        130*      89
    2   krish       50         140       91
    4   jack        60         160       83
    2   amit        15         35        76
    3   joy         30         16        69
* denotes added values
```

I tried like this:

```
final = pd.concat([df2, df1]).add(df1['buy_qty','buy_val'],df2['buy_qty','buy_val']).drop_duplicates(subset=["CONTRACT"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it's not working fine.

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72400452/15239951), here you have to `groupby` because you want to `aggregate` some values on your columns:

- `buy_qty`: `sum`
- `buy_val`: `sum`
- `factor`: `first`*

* `first` because you want to keep the values from df2 and this is the first dataframe on `pd.concat`.

```
out = (pd.concat([df2, df1]).groupby('CONTRACT', as_index=False)
         .agg({'buy_qty': 'sum', 'buy_val': 'sum', 'factor': 'first'})
print(out)

# Output
  CONTRACT  buy_qty  buy_val  factor
0      Tom       25      115      67
1     amit       15       35      76
2     jack       60      160      83
3      joy       30       16      69
4    krish       50      140      91
5     nick       46      130      89
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add` with `fill_value=0`:

```py
(df1
 .set_index('CONTRACT')
 .add(df2.set_index('CONTRACT'), fill_value=0)
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  CONTRACT  buy_qty  buy_val  factor
0      Tom     25.0    115.0   163.0
1     amit     15.0     35.0    76.0
2     jack     60.0    160.0    83.0
3      joy     30.0     16.0    69.0
4    krish     50.0    140.0    91.0
5     nick     46.0    130.0   182.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2])
df3.groupby('CONTRACT').sum()
```

result into:

```
    buy_qty     buy_val     factor
CONTRACT            
Tom     40  200     30
amit    50  140     25
jack    60  160     30
joy     60  160     30
krish   50  140     25
nick    80  240     40
```